# How to make a heads up notification like the whatsapp notification with sound

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to android programming.I want my app to display a pop-up notification( its probably called a heads up notification) on the top of the screen whether it is in background or foreground and add sound to it but cant figure out how. The code is very basic.

MyFirebaseMessageService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String TAG = "FCM";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.

        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }
}
```

MyFirebaseIdService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static String TAG = "INSTANCEID";


    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed Token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }



    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided just came from the quickstart. What actually didn't work for you here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your notification to be on the screen, or on the notification bar?

For a simple on screen notification use a Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[For a notification bar notification take a look at NotificationBuilder.](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)
[You can make your notification make sound as well.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes))

Comment: i want it to be on screen